# Extrair texto com VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Preciso criar uma macro em EXCEL que vai para uma célula que tem um texto, e traz-me um pedaço deste texto.

O problema é que o texto não tem padrão, só sei que em algum lugar deste texto será algo como `NAME:` e `EMAIL:` e eu preciso extrair para outra célula tudo o que tem entre essas duas palavras. Por exemplo:

```
Bla bla bla bla bla NOME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766 E-MAIL: josh@gmail.com bla bla bla.
```

Então eu preciso de uma macro que encontre o `NAME:` e traga tudo até `EMAIL:` e cole isso em outra célula, como: `NAME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766`

Comment: Are you aware this is a portuguese-speaking forum? Como seus dados estão dispostos na planilha? Estão todos em uma mesma coluna? Em princípio, você conseguiria o resultado desejado com uma combinação de fórmulas do próprio Excel, sem precisar recorrer a uma Macro.

Comment: You failed to notice that we speak Portuguese. Por favor, traduza a sua pergunta para o português.

Answer (score 1):

Suponha que todas as suas entradas estejam na coluna "A" a partir da linha 1;

*Suppose all your entries are in column "A" starting at row 1*

Coloque a seguinte fórmula na célula "B1":

*Place the following formula in cell "B1":*

```
=TRIM(MID(A1;FIND("NAME:";A1)+5;FIND("EMAIL:";A1)-FIND("NAME:";A1)-5))
```

Copie a fórmula para as demais células da coluna "B" e você não precisará da macro.

*Copy that formula to the remaining cells in column "B" and you're good to go with no macro.*

Answer (score 1):

VBobCat, obrigado pela ajuda mas infelizmente o VB não reconheceu a função "FIND". Mas eu achei uma alternativa como se pode ver abaixo:

```
Public LastLine As Double

Public i As Double

Public TestString As String

Public TestUpperCase As String

Public TestString2 As Double

Public TestString3 As Double

Sub Click()

On Error Resume Next

    Sheets("Plan2").Select

    LastLine = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastLine

        TestString = Cells(i, 2).Value
        TestUpperCase = UCase(TestString)
        TestString2 = InStr(TestUpperCase, "NOME:")
        TestString3 = InStr(TestUpperCase, "EMAIL:")
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(TestUpperCase, TestString2, TestString3 - TestString2)


    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma Expressão Regular pode ser utilizada.

### Código

```
Dim texto As String
Dim objCorresp As Object, objExpReg As Object
Set objExpReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
'Expressão Regular
With objExpReg
    .Pattern = "nome:[\s\S]+?(?=e-mail)"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With
texto = "Bla bla bla bla bla NOME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766 E-MAIL: josh@gmail.com bla bla bla."
Set objCorresp = objExpReg.Execute(texto)
If objCorresp.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each c In objCorresp
        Debug.Print Trim(c)
    Next c
End If
```

#### Resultado

Para o exemplo do código, o resultado é: `NOME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766`

Para uma string com múltiplas linhas:

```
texto = "Bla bla bla bla bla NOME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766 E-MAIL: josh@gmail.com bla bla bla." & vbNewLine & _
"Bla bla bla bla bla NOME: JOAO IDNUMBER: 098766 E-MAIL: josh@gmail.com bla bla bla."
```

O resultado é:

```
NOME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766
NOME: JOAO IDNUMBER: 098766
```

### Expressão Regular

A seguinte expressão pode ser utilizada: `nome:[\s\S]+?(?=e-mail)`

Em que esta expressão captura o texto que inicia com `nome:` e é seguido de qualquer caractere com quantificador *lazy* `[\s\S]+?`, antes de e-mail `(?=e-mail)`

E a [demo pode ser vista neste link](https://regex101.com/r/6sSGRq/1)

#### Habilitar o Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

## Função Definida pelo Usuário

Uma UDF pode ser criada, com o seguinte código:

```
Function extrair_texto_entre(inicio As String, fim As String, texto) As String
    Dim objCorresp As Object, objExpReg As Object
    Set objExpReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'Expressão Regular
    With objExpReg
        .Pattern = inicio & "[\s\S]+?(?=" & fim & ")"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    Set objCorresp = objExpReg.Execute(texto)
    If objCorresp.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each c In objCorresp
            extrair_texto_entre = Trim(c)
        Next c
    End If
End Function
```

#### Resultado

Esta função pode ser utilizada na Planilha da seguinte maneira:

`=extrair_texto_entre("string de início"; "string de fim"; célula ou "string")`

Em que ela pode ser utilizada ou referenciando uma célula ou entrando com uma String.

#### Com string

Nela você utiliza a função da seguinte maneira:

`=extrair_texto_entre("nome:";"e-mail";"Bla bla bla bla bla NOME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766 E-MAIL: josh@gmail.com bla bla bla.")`

E obtém o seguinte resultado: `NOME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766`

[image: Com string]

#### Com célula

Desta maneira você insere a função na planilha da seguinte forma:

`=extrair_texto_entre("nome:";"e-mail";B2)`

E obtém o resultado:

`NOME: JOSH IDNUMBER: 098766`

[image: Com célula]

Comment: estou dando uma olha nesse código e vi que me atendeu em algo importante! Porém eu queria só de exemplo que ele extraísse apenas os caracteres do meio, por exemplo 11 22 333, queria apenas exibir o "22" que está entre os outros na célula, sem exibir o "11" que no caso do seu código ele exibi dessa maneira "11 22", o que eu altero no código para ele apenas extrair o do meio??

Comment: @ElienayJunior Você precisa alterar a Expressão Regular, estude sobre expressões regulares e faça alguns testes no [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/). E em dúvida abra uma pergunta sobre expressões regulares

Comment: Eu ainda não quero entrar nesse assunto por completo de VBA e suas funções etc.. ainda estou no estudando fórmulas avançadas do próprio Excel e aninhando elas. Eu só queria mesmo um pequeno ajuste no código para não precisar inserir uma fórmula auxiliar no Excel, para remover o "11" e deixar apenas o "22"

Comment: Você precisa mudar o padrão da expressão regular aqui em `.Pattern = inicio & "[\s\S]+?(?=" & fim & ")"`, em que pega a string de inicio e a de fim e captura tudo que está entre estas duas strings

Comment: Sim eu cheguei a mexer nesse local, porém o que eu consegui fazer foi adicionar o restante dos caracteres que fora ocultos a direita da sequencia, no caso eu removi esse (?=) e deixei o ( " ) e ficou "11 22 33" extraído. Pra mim esses caracteres são estranhos, nas fórmulas do Excel o (?) que corresponde como coringa de caracteres individuais e o ( " ) indica abrir e fechar algum conteúdo, texto que fica dentro